# ASP.NET MVC 4 ViewModel inquiry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC application and this weird thing happened

I have a ViewModel called SignUp. A View is strongly typed with this ViewModel.

ViewModel code in Prj5515.ViewModels.Login.SignUp

```
public class SignUp
{
     [Required]
     public string UserId { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string Password { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string ConfirmPass { get; set; }
}
```

View Code

```
@model Prj5515.ViewModels.Login.SignUp
@using(Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <fieldset>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.UserId)</fieldset>
   <fieldset>@Html.PasswordFor(s => s.Password)</fieldset>
   <fieldset>@Html.PasswordFor(s => s.ConfirmPass)</fieldset>
}
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignUp(SignUp signup)
{
    RegisteredUser reg_user = new RegisteredUser();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But when I posted my form  in the controller the value for 'signup' was null. I tried everything and in the end I just renamed my variable 'signup' to 'signupVM' and it worked!

Can anyone tell me what was going on?

Comment: Can you show what is happening in action presenting SignUp form? Maybe you are assigning something to ViewData["SignUp"]?

Comment: I recommend to define action name and model name different

Comment: Nope, I am not using ViewData at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! I used same code and it worked for me with the same name `signup` 
You must be doing something wrong on the view.

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.SignUp

@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <fieldset>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.UserId)</fieldset>
   <fieldset>@Html.PasswordFor(s => s.Password)</fieldset>
   <fieldset>@Html.PasswordFor(s => s.ConfirmPass)</fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignUp(SignUp signup)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: did you get all the properties from the View? What I am trying to ask is that was 'signup' null?

Comment: yes I did get. that's why it might you did something wrong. You can try your code in freash controller with same model for testing.